# Datatables with Angularjs: default sorting and searching not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I used a directive to buildup database after ng-repeat finished:

```js
app.directive('repeatDone', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
        }
    }
});

function InformationController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("people").success(function(response) {
        $scope.people = response;
    });
    $scope.initDataTable = function() {
        $('#employeeTable').DataTable({
          
        });
    };
};
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="employeeTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in people" repeat-done="initDataTable()">
      <td>{{ result.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ result.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ result.gender }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The data is displayed normally, but cannot use default sorting or searching.

Is there anything wrong? What should I do to enable the sorting and searching?

Comment: Do you mean sorting by a specific column on load or when the user clicks on the column header?

Comment: @jonmrich yes, click the column header to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use datatables features in angular, since this is highly associated with execution sequences that gets overlapped and the functionality getting disturbed. You can induce a timeout specifically like below

```
setTimeout(function () {
   angular.element("#datatable").datatable();
  }, 10);
```

or do a tweak

add a blank element like this one below

```
$scope.temp = { "Name": "", "ID": "", "SSN": "" };

$scope.skills.unshift($scope.temp);

setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.skills.shift();
    $scope.apply;
}, 10);
```

What the above code does basically is adding a temp record(i.e blank) initially to the existing record collection and pull that back again, by doing this way datatable search,sort functionality is retrieved in angular.

Again this will work with a directive being created for datatable like below

```
app.directive('datatable', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AC',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                //
                scope.$watch('skills', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != undefined) {
                        if (newValue.length > 0) {
                            var rows = element.find("tbody").find('tr');
                            var fixedColumn = 3;
                            if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(element)) {
                                var tbl = $(element).dataTable();
                                tbl.fnClearTable();
                                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                    tbl.fnAddData($(rows[i]));
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                element.DataTable({ paging: true, sorting: true, "order": [[0, "asc"]], columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, "targets": fixedColumn }] });
                            }
                            element.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                                $(this).addClass('selected');
                                $(this).siblings('tr').removeClass('selected');
                            });
                            element.fadeIn();
                        }
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It gives me an error on line angular.element(...).datatable is not a function.

Comment: hi newly in angular, this is a not good way, why datatable not giving its by default functionality directly in angular?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with my table not searching nor sorting after populating the table.

the thing missing for angularjs is datatable="ng" on the table
i had datatable="" initially.

Hope this helps